# Kendo grid bound to dynamic data source does not support empty rows in static grid

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a Kendo grid that has a static size of 6 rows, the data comes dynamically from remote source, each property of data being bound to a specific column.

The grid should always show 6 rows even if the rows are empty (No data to show on them), I achieved this by setting empty data to the rows in model side, in case there was less than 6 data items.

I can add, edit and remove data per each grid-row, and the grid being static in size I would like to support functionality where one can add new data item to row 1, and for example row 5 so that when the data is reload it always shows the data on those exact rows. The default functionality in Kendo-grid would be that it shows the data which was added to row 5 in row 2 after the reload.

Is there a way of forcing Kendo to put data to a specific row in grid, even if there might be empty rows before and after this one row? I understood that the Grid has uid for rows, which are changed after reload thus being unuseful in this case. The grid does not have a template, it's simply defined with Html.Kendo()-bindings.

Data binding:

```
    @(Html.Kendo()
              .Grid<DataStructure>()
              .Name("grid")
              .Columns(columns =>
              {
                  columns.Bound(o => o.ListActionIndex)
                        .Width(100)
                        .Sortable(false);

                  columns.Bound(o => o.Action)
                        .Filterable(false)
                        .Width(100)
                        .Sortable(false);

                  columns.Bound(o => o.Status)
                      .Width(40)
                      .EditorViewData(new { Width = 40 })
                      .HtmlAttributes(new { title = "test" });

 })
              .Editable(e => e.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine))


.DataSource(source =>
              {
                  source.Ajax()
                         .Read(read => read.Action("GetData", "DataStructure").Data("additionalData")).PageSize(6)
                         .Model(model =>
                          {
                              model.Field(o => o.Action).Editable(false);
                              model.Field(o => o.Status).Editable(false);
                              model.Field(o => o.ListActionIndex).Editable(false);

                          })
                          .Model(model => model.Id(o => o.ListActionIndex));

              })
```

Comment: How you impliment empty rows? You should post some code, grid definition and empty rows generate method. By the way you just need to store index of row and after databiding event reorder rows by index field

Comment: Added the binding example. Empty rows are created by just adding models without data set in controller so that there always will be 6 rows shown even if they or some of them are empty. So the list from controller  having the models is always filled up up to 6 items. It's just a list returned as a JsonResult. Your tip of reordering by row index might do the trick, I'll try that next.

Comment: I tought it was not possible to create the fixed size grid (row-wise) without using those empty placeholder data items. If I am wrong in this and it could be done without I would like to see an example on how to do it.

Comment: As I know `kendo` don't have such mechanizm